# Utility for knowing backend service calls a wcf based service does

Tags: wcf

I am working on a requirement to know what back-end service contracts are being invoked via a service wrapper (wcf service).

This is a enterprise level service platform where we have created a WCF based service which invokes different different Back-end Service contracts.

The requirement is to know which WCF Contract calls which back-end service contracts.

Comment: so far only thing I thought of is using Reflection (.NET) to load the assembly for that WCF Service and loop through its Method attributes , but still wondering how to get to the implementation details for any contract in that service so that to know what service contracts it calls..!

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of the service? If so, then why not _look_ at the source and write a list of all the back-end calls it makes. Maybe even add Trace.WriteLine calls before each back-end call, and one at the beginning and end of each service operation.

Comment: John that sounds like a good idea , though it needs some work , what I want to come up with is a fast and automated way to know this info.

Comment: It's not practical. Consider that your service might call some other class library that might call another class library that might finally call some service you know nothing about, possibly without using WCF.